# migration not working with django and docker?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx

I have a project where I have developed a Django application which I am trying to containerize and host on my raspberry pi. During development on my local environment the container is working fine (builds and run without any errors). However when I try to run it on my server the migrations just wont work. For some strange reason it is not including my custom user model during migrations. The [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdt1C.png) follows a basic pattern with one folder for the app, and another containing the webserver (nginx). The [Django-compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O6OW.png) creates three images (postgres, django, nginx). The main logic related to the Containers could be found in the main [Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiiic.png). To run the migrations and start the django application Ive included a [bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYJP8.png) that migrates all models. However, during the build I get the following error:

```css
app_1    | False
app_1    | Operations to perform:
app_1    |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, token_blacklist
app_1    | Running migrations:
db_1     | 2021-06-14 00:36:00.879 UTC [35] ERROR:  relation "users_newuser" does not exist
db_1     | 2021-06-14 00:36:00.879 UTC [35] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_users_newuser_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users_newuser" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
app_1    |   Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
app_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
app_1    | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_newuser" does not exist
```

In regards to the Django application I've added each model in every admin.py file and modified the settings by extending the INSTALLED_APPS and AUTH_USER_MODEL. As the error message indicates it seems to be something wrong with my migrations file. Thus I've removed these migrations file to no avail, the error still persists.

Any suggestion are appreciated as I have exhausted all possible solutions I can figure out by myself.

Comment: According to the error message, I suppose there is something wrong with your migration files. You should consider delete all migration files and makemigrations again (you might lose all data)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. However, the files does not contain any migration files, I've already deleted them as i wanted to ensure that this was not the problem. However, the problem still persists. However, it could be that the image is not completely deleted and contain the migration files. Its difficult to test this however as i cant connect to the terminal if it is not running. However the commands that I perform to delete the containers are: 
1. docker-compose stop
2. docker-compose rm 
3. docker-compose down
4 docker volume rm 
5 docker system prune --all

Comment: The error happens when docker run python manage.py migrate, so that's why I guess your Django migration files are messed up because of changing models while working. You can follow this guide to reset migrations https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: There's another way to test if your migration files are messed up or not. git clone this repo to a new folder, and run docker-compose up from there (in your local).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by adding the missing models manually and then running the migrations. I don't know exactly why this solver the problem though. If someone knows please inform me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you needed to add the models manually. Looking at your bash script, it seems you are missing `python manage.py makemigrations` line just before `migrate` line. I had the same issue and i fixed it by adding that line as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716358/how-do-i-run-migrations-in-dockerized-django). This question is four months old, let hope someone gets help in the future